# How to get Country ISO code in OpenCart invoice?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I want zone code in stead of Zone name and Country code in stead of Country name in the invoice only.

**Like:** 
First Name, 
Address line 1,
West Sussex, United Kingdom

**As:**
First Name, 
Address line 1, SXW, UK

I've made some modification in the following file:

**public_html/_admin/controller/sale/order.php**

```
            if ($order_info['shipping_address_format']) {
                $format = $order_info['shipping_address_format'];
            } else {
                $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . ", " . '{address_2}' . ", " . '{city} {postcode}' . ", " . '{zone_code}' . "\n" . '{country_code}'; 
            }
```

I'm getting the zone code fine, but not getting Country code, it's showing '{country_code}' only.

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update  file as below:
     `$find = array(
                '{firstname}',
                '{lastname}',
                '{company}',
                '{address_1}',
                '{address_2}',
                '{city}',
                '{postcode}',
                '{zone}',
                '{zone_code}',
                '{country}',
                '{country_code}'
            );

```
        $replace = array(
            'firstname' => $order_info['payment_firstname'],
            'lastname'  => $order_info['payment_lastname'],
            'company'   => $order_info['payment_company'],
            'address_1' => $order_info['payment_address_1'],
            'address_2' => $order_info['payment_address_2'],
            'city'      => $order_info['payment_city'],
            'postcode'  => $order_info['payment_postcode'],
            'zone'      => $order_info['payment_zone'],
            'zone_code' => $order_info['payment_zone_code'],
            'country'   => $order_info['payment_country'],
            'country_code' => $order_info['shipping_iso_code_3']
        );

        $data['payment_address'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', preg_replace(array("/\s\s+/", "/\r\r+/", "/\n\n+/"), '<br />', trim(str_replace($find, $replace, $format))));

        // Shipping Address
        if ($order_info['shipping_address_format']) {
            $format = $order_info['shipping_address_format'];
        } else {
            $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country_code}';
        }`
```

Added country_code in both $find and $replace array.

Comment: thanks, solved it yesterday same way :) but, thanks a lot for the response :)